# Bootstrap 3 ruins mobile full page background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for my interface page on a site i manage. I set my full page background image using this CSS:

```
background-image:url('/path/to/image.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

It works great... On desktop. On mobile, the image gets resized to to a very small resolution and it gets pushed up, above a bootstrap 3 panel.

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rFEA.png). On desktop, the picture covers the full page.
And here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89cpmctt/4/).

The thing is that it works great if i remove the bootstrap code; for example on another page not using bootstrap, the same CSS is used. The image scales nicely on desktop and on mobile.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used; `<img src="/resources/ui_bg.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0‌​;z-index:-5000;" alt="">`

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe depending on the browser you are using on the mobile phone?

Try adding:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

I might be wrong, but worth a shot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, it does not change anything... this is really weird

Comment: Hey i fixed it, changed the method to this: <img src="/resources/ui_bg.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-5000;" alt="">  Not it does not look as good but it's ok. Thanks for the help!